# Count the frequency of specific nodes in an XML document

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This may have been covered before, but after much googling, I can't seem to find any examples.  Essentially I'm trying to get a frequency count of the number of time a book is taken out on loan.  My XML tree is given below, along with the XSL and resulting output.

```
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="LoanStyler.xsl"?>
<loans>
  <loan id="0001">
    <summary>
      <user>AAA</user>
      <dateOut>2011-01-01</dateOut>
      <dateDue>2011-01-14</dateDue>
    </summary>
    <details>
      <books>
        <name>Book7</name>
        <name>Book4</name>
      </books>
    </details>
  </loan>
  <loan id="0002">
    <summary>
      <user>BBB</user>
      <dateOut>2011-01-10</dateOut>
      <dateDue>2011-01-24</dateDue>
    </summary>
    <details>
      <books>
        <name>Book1</name>
        <name>Book2</name>
        <name>Book4</name>
        <name>Book6</name>
      </books>
    </details>
  </loan>
  <loan id="0003">
    <summary>
      <user>CCC</user>
      <dateOut>2011-01-14</dateOut>
      <dateDue>2011-01-28</dateDue>
    </summary>
    <details>
      <books>
        <name>Book1</name>
        <name>Book3</name>
        <name>Book4</name>
        <name>Book7</name>
        <name>Book8</name>
      </books>
    </details>
  </loan>
  <loan id="0004">
    <summary>
      <user>DDD</user>
      <dateOut>2011-02-01</dateOut>
      <dateDue>2011-02-14</dateDue>
    </summary>
    <details>
      <books>
        <name>Book1</name>
        <name>Book2</name>
        <name>Book4</name>
      </books>
    </details>
  </loan>
</loans>

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key 
    name="books-by-name" 
    match="//loans/loan/details/books" 
    use="name" 
  />


<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h1>Loan Records Log</h1>
    <table Border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Loan ID</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Date Out</th>
            <th>Date Due</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="//loans/loan">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="summary/user"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="summary/dateOut"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="summary/dateDue"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>

    <table Border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Book name</th>
            <th>Count</th>
        </tr>

        <xsl:for-each select="books[count(. | key('books-by-name', name)[1]) = 1]">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="count(key('books-by-name', name))" /></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Loan Records Log
Loan ID User    Date Out    Date Due
0001    AAA 2011-01-01  2011-01-14
0002    BBB 2011-01-10  2011-01-24
0003    CCC 2011-01-14  2011-01-28
0004    DDD 2011-02-01  2011-02-14
Book name   Count
```

As you can see the attempt at Muenchian Grouping doesn't seem to be working.  Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong, as the only examples I can find don't appear to have helped.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of the problem and a quick and easy solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem is here**:

```
   <xsl:for-each select="books
                 [count(. | key('books-by-name', name)[1]) = 1]">
```

**Must be**:

```
   <xsl:for-each select="loans/loan/details/books
                 [count(. | key('books-by-name', name)[1]) = 1]">
```

At the location the above instruction is specified, the current node is`/` and `/` doesn't have a child element `books`.

Also, there is a logic error. The key must be different.

**Here is a corrected solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key      name="books-by-name"
    match="books/name"      use="."    />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Loan Records Log</h1>
                <table Border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Loan ID</th>
                        <th>User</th>
                        <th>Date Out</th>
                        <th>Date Due</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//loans/loan">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="summary/user"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="summary/dateOut"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="summary/dateDue"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
                <table Border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Book name</th>
                        <th>Count</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="loans/loan/details/books/name
                            [count(. | key('books-by-name', name)[1]) = 1]">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="count(key('books-by-name',.))" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<loans>
    <loan id="0001">
        <summary>
            <user>AAA</user>
            <dateOut>2011-01-01</dateOut>
            <dateDue>2011-01-14</dateDue>
        </summary>
        <details>
            <books>
                <name>Book7</name>
                <name>Book4</name>
            </books>
        </details>
    </loan>
    <loan id="0002">
        <summary>
            <user>BBB</user>
            <dateOut>2011-01-10</dateOut>
            <dateDue>2011-01-24</dateDue>
        </summary>
        <details>
            <books>
                <name>Book1</name>
                <name>Book2</name>
                <name>Book4</name>
                <name>Book6</name>
            </books>
        </details>
    </loan>
    <loan id="0003">
        <summary>
            <user>CCC</user>
            <dateOut>2011-01-14</dateOut>
            <dateDue>2011-01-28</dateDue>
        </summary>
        <details>
            <books>
                <name>Book1</name>
                <name>Book3</name>
                <name>Book4</name>
                <name>Book7</name>
                <name>Book8</name>
            </books>
        </details>
    </loan>
    <loan id="0004">
        <summary>
            <user>DDD</user>
            <dateOut>2011-02-01</dateOut>
            <dateDue>2011-02-14</dateDue>
        </summary>
        <details>
            <books>
                <name>Book1</name>
                <name>Book2</name>
                <name>Book4</name>
            </books>
        </details>
    </loan>
</loans>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Loan Records Log</h1>
      <table Border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Loan ID</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Date Out</th>
            <th>Date Due</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>0001</td>
            <td>AAA</td>
            <td>2011-01-01</td>
            <td>2011-01-14</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>0002</td>
            <td>BBB</td>
            <td>2011-01-10</td>
            <td>2011-01-24</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>0003</td>
            <td>CCC</td>
            <td>2011-01-14</td>
            <td>2011-01-28</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>0004</td>
            <td>DDD</td>
            <td>2011-02-01</td>
            <td>2011-02-14</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table Border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Book name</th>
            <th>Count</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Book7</td>
            <td>2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Book4</td>
            <td>4</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Book1</td>
            <td>3</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Book2</td>
            <td>2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Book4</td>
            <td>4</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Book6</td>
            <td>1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Book1</td>
            <td>3</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Book3</td>
            <td>1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Book4</td>
            <td>4</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Book7</td>
            <td>2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Book8</td>
            <td>1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Book1</td>
            <td>3</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Book2</td>
            <td>2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Book4</td>
            <td>4</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre, Thanks for your reply. However when adding the extra path into the select value as suggested, I only get the following output:

Book name Count
Book7 4

Where as I am trying to achieve:

Book name Count
Book7 2
Book4 4
Book1 3
Book2 2
Book3 1
Book8 1

I thought the for-each would take care of the looping through the distinct books, and the second count would return the number of each distinct one.

Comment: Apologies, for the lack of formatting in the previous comment, but I tihnk you can see what I'm getting at.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, there was also a logic error in your solution -- I updated my answer and it now shows a complete corrected solution.

Comment: @Dimitre: Thanks thats brilliant.  I think I can see where I was going wrong now.

Comment: @Dimitre: +1 For a correct answer. I think you should add the explanation of the multivalue key problem because a lot of people think that keys are one-to-one and not many-to-many.